# Cannot implement interface member because it doesn't have matching return type

Tags: c#

I'm working on an abstract algebra library for C#, but am having trouble with implementing interfaces. I have gotten the implementation to work for certain groups, but attempting to create rings is giving me some serious problems. In particular, I've got the following:

```
public class Scaffolding {

public interface IMonoid<T> : ISemiGroup<T> {
        T Identity { get; set; }
    }

public interface IGroup<T> : IMonoid<T> {
        T Inverse(T a);
    }

 public interface IRing<T> {
       IGroup<T> AdditiveStructure { get; set; }
       IMonoid<T> MultiplicativeStructure { get; set; }
    }
}

 public class ModularMonoid : Scaffolding.IMonoid<int> {
       // Implements all necessary monoid properties
    }

 public class ModularGroup : Scaffolding.IGroup<int> {
       // Implements all necessary group properties
    }

 public class ModularRing : Scaffolding.IRing<int> {
    public ModularGroup AdditiveStructure { get; set; }
    public ModularMonoid MultiplicativeStructure { get; set; }

    // Implement ring-specific properties
}
```

I get an error stating that 'ModularRing' does not implement interface member 'Scaffolding.IRing.AdditiveStructure'. 'ModularRing.AdditiveStructure' cannot implement 'Scaffolding.IRing.AdditiveStructure' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Scaffolding.IGroup'. I get a similar error for the MultiplicativeStructure. This is strange to me, because both the ModularGroup and ModularMonoid implement IGroup and IMonoid respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those classes implement the interfaces, but that interface doesn't say "The type of the `AdditiveStructure` property is something that implements `IGroup<T>`" - it says that the type of the `AdditiveStructure` property *is* `IGroup<T>`. To implement the interface, you have to match return types *exactly*.

If you want to be able to implement the interface like that, you'd need to change the interface, potentially like this:

```
public interface IRing<T, TGroup, TMonoid>
    where TGroup : IGroup<T>
    where TMonoid : IMonoid<T>
{
   TGroup AdditiveStructure { get; set; }
   TMonoid MultiplicativeStructure { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it as:

```
public class ModularRing : Scaffolding.IRing<int, ModularGroup, ModularMonoid>
{
    public ModularGroup AdditiveStructure { get; set; }
    public ModularMonoid MultiplicativeStructure { get; set; }        
}
```

Alternatively, you should consider making the properties read-only. That way, if you're happy with the `ModularRing` users only using the `IGroup<int>` and `IMonoid<int>` definitions (rather than depending on anything extra exposed on `ModularGroup` and `ModularMonoid`) then you could stick with just the single type parameter, which would simplify things quite a lot. For example:

```
public interface IMonoid<T> : ISemiGroup<T>
{
    T Identity { get; }
}

public interface IGroup<T> : IMonoid<T>
 {
    T Inverse(T a);
}

public interface IRing<T>
{
   IGroup<T> AdditiveStructure { get; }
   IMonoid<T> MultiplicativeStructure { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class ModularRing : Scaffolding.IRing<int>
{
    public IGroup<int> AdditiveStructure { get; } = new ModularGroup();
    public IMonoid<int> MultiplicativeStructure { get; } = new ModularMonoid();
}
```

(Or accept them in the constructor; I don't know enough about what you're trying to do with them.)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I can't mark your answer as the solution yet, but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Rich: Goodo - I've expanded the second half of the answer, with the read-only version (with just one type parameter). In my experience, that's a simpler approach in most cases... otherwise it's easy to drown in type parameters.

Comment: For the read-only version, I'd suggest using explicit interface implementations to emulate covariant return types. That is, the public AdditiveStructure property could still have a type of ModularGroup, and the explicit interface implementation (which would simply return this.AdditiveStructure) would have a type of IGroup<int>.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: I'd do that if I wanted to expose the `ModularGroup` aspect, but not otherwise. I didn't want to go into *too* much detail :)